# detecting media device with my own function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why the following code won't work?

```
 var detectDevice;
    var mlg = function(){
        $(window).on('load resize',function(){
            if($(this).width >= 768){
                return detectDevice = 'mlg';
            }
        })
    }
    if(detectDevice=='mlg'){alert('test')}
```

---

**Update:** I need to use something like this:

```
var detectDevice;
var mlg = function(){
 //  detectDevice = 'mlg';
}
var mxs = function(){
 //  detectDevice = 'mxs';
}
if(detectDevice=='mlg'){
alert('test');
}
```

Comment: because of this `if($(this).width >= 768px){`

Comment: should be `if($(this).width() >= 768){`

Comment: $(this) is targeting to window, no?

Comment: basically, your code has wrong syntax and wrong function call

Comment: so the expected result is after load/resize, if the width >= 768 then alert "Test", right?

Comment: it's not alerting at all.

Comment: check my new answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/22321494/414184

Answer (score 1):

[width()](http://api.jquery.com/width/) is a function try this,

```
$(window).on('load resize',function(){// remove quotes from window
   if($(this).width() >= 768){ //use width() and 768 rempve px
       detectDevice = 'mlg';// remove return
   }
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zA8Ld/1/)

Comment: try my updated answer and remove `quotes` from window.

Comment: is this alerting in your browser? I can't see the alert.

Comment: I can't see in this too.

Comment: See the new [one](http://jsfiddle.net/zA8Ld/3/) and resize the `window` to check the `width`.

Answer (score 1):

`width` is method and not property.So it should be `width()`.also use `$(window)` instead of $('window'):

```
$(window).on('load resize',function(){
        if($(this).width() >= 768){//or $(window).width()
            return detectDevice = 'mlg';
        }
    })
```

Comment: @BangDao: Did not see that.Thanks.

Comment: you also forgot to replace `768px` by `768`

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
var detectDevice;
function mlg(){
    if($(window).width() >= 768){
        detectDevice = 'mlg';
        if(detectDevice=='mlg'){
            alert('test');
        }
    };
};
$(window).on('load resize', function(){mlg();});
```

<kbd>[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cj3uA/)</kbd>